# How can I merge matching keys to into arrays via another key?

Tags: json, jq

I have a GraphQL schema file with deeply nested object metadata that I'd like to extract into arrays of child properties. The original file is over 75000 lines long but I was able to successfully extract the Types & fields for each object using this command:

`jq '.data.__schema.types[] | {name: .name, fields: .fields[]?.name?}' schema.json > output.json`

Output:

```
{
  "name": "UsersConnection",
  "fields": "nodes"
}
{
  "name": "UsersConnection",
  "fields": "edges"
}
{
  "name": "UsersConnection",
  "fields": "pageInfo"
}
{
  "name": "UsersConnection",
  "fields": "totalCount"
}
{
  "name": "UsersEdge",
  "fields": "cursor"
}
{
  "name": "UsersEdge",
  "fields": "node"
}
...
```

But the output I want looks more like this:

```
[{
  "name": "UsersConnection",
  "fields": [ "nodes", "edges", "pageInfo", "totalCount" ]
},
{
  "name": "UsersEdge",
  "fields": [ "cursor", "node" ]
}]
```

I was able to do this by comma-separating each object, surrounding the output with `{ "data": [ -OUTPUT- ]}` & the command:

`jq 'map(. |= (group_by(.name) | map(first + {fields: map(.fields)})))' output.json > output2.json`

How can I do this with a single command?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `.data.__schema.types` is an array, and so is `.fields`, you could try `map` in both cases:

```bash
.data.__schema.types | map({name: .name, fields: (.fields | map(.name))})
```

Comment: I was able to solve it like this: ```jq '.data.__schema.types[] | [{name: .name, fields: [.fields[]?.name?]}]'```. Do you know if there is a performance difference between maps and casting the output with brackets?

Answer (score 0):

I totally missed that I put the fields object inside brackets like this:

`jq '.data.__schema.types[] | {name: .name, fields: [.fields[]?.name?]}'`

Keeping this up for posterity in case someone else is trying to do the same thing

***Update**: I was able to get a cleaner, comma-separated result like this:*

`jq 'reduce .data.__schema.types[] as $d (null; .[$d.name] += [$d.fields[]?.name?])'`